# Complex Shortcut Installshield using variables

Tags: installation, installshield, shortcut

I need to create a shortcut for my application in Installshield, and the path to do so is:

```
C:\app\bin\exe.exe -basekey ini -ininame settings.ini -p cal.p -pf s:\pfs\sec_l_oea.pf
```

This shortcut is essentially split up into three bits:

```
C:\app\bin\exe.exe
```

This is the location of a pre existing software that I would like to find using System Search.

```
-basekey ini -ininame settings.ini -p cal.p -pf
```

This will always be the same and does not need any variables

```
s:\pfs\sec_l_oea.pf
```

The user should have to browse to find this file.

My problem is I don't know how to get the path for part one, I have set up a System Search to hopefully find it, and store it in the "PROWIN" variable, however, how do I access that variable when setting a shortcut?

I could also do with knowing how to take a user variable (from installation) and set the shortcut depending on that for part 3.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: OpenEdge, 18th Century Programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the file stored in a variable/property I think it can be used in multiple places by putting the name in a string with square brackets around it.

Your argument might look something like this:

`-basekey ini -ininame settings.ini -p cal.p -pf [PROWIN]`

As a side point: In the installshield termanology, dynamically stored values are always strings and they are refered to "properties" not variables, this might help with future searches.

Comment: Whats the best way to turn user input into a property then? I can't figure it out and am tempted to turn the Customer Information dialog on, and then modify it to say where is your .pf file, then use [USERNAME] as the [PROWIN] property

Comment: I think your approach is fine with the search. However, it does not give the user a fallback option if the search fails.

Controls on a Dialog feed their values into properties. You can make your own custom dialog (a real pain), or use/add a control on an existing one as you suggested. You can edit a control to change the property it goes into.

I think the best solution would be to use the System Search to put the value into a property and then also show it in a dialog, so the user can edit/fix it to be what they want or leave it as is. Try to keep it simple, IS can get complicated quickly.

Comment: Hey Owen. This part of my installer is all sorted now. The System Search result can be edited by the user if it is empty/wrong. I got the browse functionality by following a tutorial here: http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/FileOpenDialog-HowTo.htm (For anyone with similar problems)